# Finding all paths of an n digit lock

Tags: java

I'm new to Stack Overflow but I've tried researching this question before and I've come up with not to much.  I am currently working on a homework assignment and I'm extremely confused on how to use a hint that my professor gave me.  The purpose of the assignment is to find the shortest path from a start code to a target code in an n digit lock.  Here's an example
Start Code: 5555
Target Code: 7777

We also have some forbidden codes that we can't pass along the way
Ex.
number of forbidden codes = 4
6555
5655
5565
5556

Given this information we can come up with our shortest path to be
D1 4555
U2 4655
U2 4755
U1 5755
U1 6755
U1 7755
U3 7765
U3 7775
U4 7776
U4 7777

For a total of 10 moves.  This also needs to be in lexicographical order.  Meaning theres multiple 10 moves that can be made to get to this target code but I need one that is as close to being in the form of
D1 D2 ... DN U1 U2 ... UN

Now I've come up with a number of solutions for this problem.  My first attempt was to go through the n digit code and identify all the numbers that need to be decreased first,  then I set each digit from left to right order.  This generates a few answers that satisfy the assignment, however, it doesn't solve the issue of running into a forbidden code somewhere in the middle of the path and having an extra long detour (which is essentially not the shortest path).

Now the hint that I was given not to long ago was to use a queue of all possible one digit moves but I have absolutely no idea how to obtain the shortest path from this queue.  Here is my code so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Element
{
int index;
StringBuilder stringIndex;
boolean isForbid;
boolean visited;
boolean isTarget;
boolean pathForbid;
ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> paths;

Element()
{
    index = 0;
    isForbid = false;
    visited = false;
    isTarget = false;
    pathForbid = false;
    stringIndex = new StringBuilder();
    paths = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
}
Element(int ind, boolean forb, boolean vis, boolean tar)
{
    index = ind;
    stringIndex = new StringBuilder();
    stringIndex.append(ind);
    isForbid = forb;
    visited = vis;
    isTarget = tar;
    pathForbid = false;
    paths = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
}
void setPath(int index, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> newList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        newList.add(index);
        paths.add(newList);
    }
}
void setForbid(boolean forbid)
{
    isForbid = forbid;
}
}

public class Solution
{
public Element moveOne(Element e, int index, int direction)
{
    int num = Character.getNumericValue(e.stringIndex.charAt(index));
    if(num == 0 && direction == 1)
        num = 9;
    else if(num == 9 && direction == 0)
        num = 0;
    else if(direction == 0)
        num++;
    else if(direction == 1)
        num--;

    String stringNum = Integer.toString(num);

    e.stringIndex.replace(index, index+1, stringNum);
    e.index = Integer.parseInt(e.stringIndex.toString());

    return e;
}

public void printEl(Element e)
{
    System.out.println(e.index);
    System.out.println(e.stringIndex);
    System.out.println(e.isForbid);
    System.out.println(e.visited);
    System.out.println(e.isTarget);
    System.out.println(e.paths);
}

public void calcOneMoves(Element e, int n, Element[] all, int start)
{
    int num = 0, index = start, newIndex = 0, w = 0;
    String stringNum = "";
    //current.append(start);
    boolean forbidden = false;

    ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> newPath = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
    LinkedList<Integer> newList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    for(int j = 0; j < 2*n; j++)
    {
        StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder();
        w = j;
        newList = e.paths.get(j);
        current.append(newList.getLast());
        if(j >= n)
            w = j - n;

        if(j < (2*n)/2)
        {
            if(j % 2 == 0)
            {
                num = Character.getNumericValue(current.charAt(w));
                num--;
                stringNum = Integer.toString(num);
                current.replace(w, w+1, stringNum);
                newIndex = Integer.parseInt(current.toString());
                newList.add(newIndex);
                if(all[newIndex].isForbid)
                    newList.addFirst(-2);
                else if(all[newIndex].isTarget)
                    newList.addFirst(-1);
                else
                    all[newIndex].visited = true;
            }
            else if(j % 2 == 1)
            {
                num = Character.getNumericValue(current.charAt(w));
                num--;
                stringNum = Integer.toString(num);
                current.replace(w, w+1, stringNum);
                newIndex = Integer.parseInt(current.toString());
                newList.add(newIndex);

                if(all[newIndex].isForbid)
                    newList.addFirst(-2);
                else if(all[newIndex].isTarget)
                    newList.addFirst(-1);
                else
                    all[newIndex].visited = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(j % 2 == 1)
            {
                num = Character.getNumericValue(current.charAt(w));
                num++;
                stringNum = Integer.toString(num);
                current.replace(w, w+1, stringNum);
                newIndex = Integer.parseInt(current.toString());
                newList.add(newIndex);
                if(all[newIndex].isForbid)
                    newList.addFirst(-2);
                else if(all[newIndex].isTarget)
                    newList.addFirst(-1);
            }
            else if(j % 2 == 0)
            {
                num = Character.getNumericValue(current.charAt(w));
                num++;
                stringNum = Integer.toString(num);
                current.replace(w, w+1, stringNum);
                newIndex = Integer.parseInt(current.toString());
                newList.add(newIndex);
                if(all[newIndex].isForbid)
                    newList.addFirst(-2);
                else if(all[newIndex].isTarget)
                    newList.addFirst(-1);
                else
                    all[newIndex].visited = true;
            }   
        }

        e.stringIndex.replace(0, n, Integer.toString(start));
        //e.paths.add(newList);
        current = e.stringIndex;
    }
}

public int findDiff(Element temp, Element target, int index)
{
    int num1 = Character.getNumericValue(temp.stringIndex.charAt(index));
    int num2 = Character.getNumericValue(target.stringIndex.charAt(index));

    return num1 - num2;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    System.setIn(new FileInputStream(new File("Input.txt")));
    String[] upDown = {"U", "D"};
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Solution s = new Solution();
    int i, f, n, size = 1, pow, count = 0, difference = 0, direction = 0, tempNum = 0;
    boolean goAhead = true, failed = false, done = false, stillDecreasing = true;
    Element startCode;
    Element targetCode;
    Element tempCode = new Element();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    n = scanner.nextInt();

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        size = size*10;

    Element arr[] = new Element[size];

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Element e = new Element(i, false, false, false);
        e.setPath(i, n);
        arr[i] = e;
    }
    boolean decreaseFirst[] = new boolean[n];

    tempNum = scanner.nextInt();
    startCode = new Element(tempNum, false, true, false);
    startCode.setPath(tempNum, n);

    tempNum = scanner.nextInt();
    targetCode = new Element(tempNum, false, true, true);
    targetCode.setPath(tempNum, n);

    arr[startCode.index] = startCode;
    arr[targetCode.index] = targetCode;


    if(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        f = scanner.nextInt();

        for(i = 0; i < f; i++)
        {
            tempNum = scanner.nextInt();
            Element newElement = new Element(tempNum, true, true, false);
            newElement.setPath(tempNum, n);
            arr[newElement.index] = newElement;
        }
    }
    tempCode = startCode;
    int tempIndex = startCode.index;

    s.calcOneMoves(tempCode, n, arr, tempCode.index);
    s.calcOneMoves(tempCode, n, arr, tempCode.index);
    s.printEl(tempCode);

    if(arr[startCode.index].isForbid || arr[targetCode.index].isForbid)
    {
        goAhead = false;
        failed = true;
    }
    /*if(n == 1 && goAhead)
    {
        difference = s.findDiff(tempCode, targetCode, 0);
        while(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(0) != targetCode.stringIndex.charAt(0))
        {
            if(difference > 5 || (difference > -5 && difference < 0))
            {
                tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, 0, 0);
                count++;
                direction = 0;
                if(arr[tempCode.index] == null)
                    arr[tempCode.index] = tempCode;
                else if(arr[tempCode.index].isForbid)
                {
                    for(int w = 0; w < count; w++)
                        tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, 0, 1);
                    count = 0;
                    difference = 5;
                    output = new StringBuilder();
                    if(done)
                    {
                        tempCode = targetCode;
                        failed = true;
                    }
                    else
                        done = true;
                }
            }
            else if(difference <= 5 || (difference <= -5 && difference < 0))
            {
                tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, 0, 1);
                count++;
                direction = 1;
                if(arr[tempCode.index] == null)
                    arr[tempCode.index] = tempCode;
                else if(arr[tempCode.index].isForbid)
                {
                    for(int w = 0; w < count; w++)
                        tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, 0, 0);
                    count = 0;
                    difference = 6;
                    output = new StringBuilder();
                    if(done)
                    {
                        tempCode = targetCode;
                        failed = true;
                    }
                    else
                        done = true;
                }
            }
            output.append("\n" + upDown[direction]+ "" + (i+1) + " " + tempCode.index);
        }
    }
    if(goAhead)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            while(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(i) != targetCode.stringIndex.charAt(i) && stillDecreasing)
            {
                difference = s.findDiff(tempCode, targetCode, i);
                if((difference <= 5 && difference > 0)|| (difference <= -5 && difference < 0))
                {
                    tempCode.isForbid = false;
                    tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 1);
                    count++;
                    direction = 1;
                    if(arr[tempCode.index] == null)
                        arr[tempCode.index] = tempCode;
                    else if(arr[tempCode.index].isForbid)
                    {
                        tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 0);
                        count--;
                        stillDecreasing = false;
                    }
                if(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(0) == '0')
                    output.append("\n" + upDown[direction] + "" + (i+1) + " " + "0" + tempCode.index);
                else
                    output.append("\n" + upDown[direction] + "" + (i+1) + " " + tempCode.index);
                }
                else
                    stillDecreasing = false;
            }
            stillDecreasing = true;
        }
    }
    if(goAhead)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            while(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(i) != targetCode.stringIndex.charAt(i))
            {
                difference = s.findDiff(tempCode, targetCode, i);

                if(difference > 5 || (difference > -5 && difference < 0))
                {
                    tempCode.isForbid = false;
                    tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 0);
                    count++;
                    direction = 0;

                    if(arr[tempCode.index] == null)
                        arr[tempCode.index] = tempCode;
                    else if (arr[tempCode.index].isForbid)
                    {
                        tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 1);
                        tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 1);
                        direction = 1;
                        if(arr[tempCode.index] == null)
                            arr[tempCode.index] = tempCode;
                        else if(arr[tempCode.index].isForbid)
                        {
                            tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 0);
                            count--;
                        }
                        tempCode.isForbid = true;
                    }
                    if(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(0) == '0')
                        output.append("\n" + upDown[direction] + "" + (i+1) + " " + "0" + tempCode.index);
                    else
                        output.append("\n" + upDown[direction] + "" + (i+1) + " " + tempCode.index);
                    if(tempCode.isForbid)
                        break;
                }
                else if(difference <= 5 || (difference <= -5 && difference < 0))
                {
                    tempCode.isForbid = false;
                    tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 1);
                    count++;
                    direction = 1;
                    if(arr[tempCode.index] == null)
                        arr[tempCode.index] = tempCode;
                    else if (arr[tempCode.index].isForbid)
                    {
                        direction = 0;
                        tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 0);
                        tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 0);
                        if(arr[tempCode.index] == null)
                            arr[tempCode.index] = tempCode;
                        else if(arr[tempCode.index].isForbid)
                        {
                            tempCode = s.moveOne(tempCode, i, 1);
                            count--;
                        }
                        tempCode.isForbid = true;
                    }

                    if(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(0) == '0')
                        output.append("\n" + upDown[direction] + "" + (i+1) + " " + "0" + tempCode.index);
                    else
                        output.append("\n" + upDown[direction] + "" + (i+1) + " " + tempCode.index);
                    if(tempCode.isForbid)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(0) != targetCode.stringIndex.charAt(0) && tempCode.stringIndex.charAt((1)) == targetCode.stringIndex.charAt((1)) && n != 1)
                i = -1;
            else if(tempCode.stringIndex.charAt(i) != targetCode.stringIndex.charAt(i) && tempCode.stringIndex.charAt((i)) == targetCode.stringIndex.charAt((i)) && n != 1)
                i = -1;
            else if(i == (n - 1) && tempCode.index != targetCode.index)
                failed = true;
        }
    }

    /*if(failed)
        System.out.println(-1);
    else
        System.out.println(count + "" + output);*/

}
}
```

As of right now this code is slightly messy because i've been implementing a bunch of different ideas.  I will be cleaning this up once I find a solution that works.  The code that is commented out at the bottom is how I implement my one path starting with decrease first then setting each digit from left to right order.

If you run this code right now with the input being in the format of

4 //number of digits in the lock in the range of 0 < n <= 7
5555 //start code
7777 //target code
4 // number of forbidden codes
6555
5655
5565
5556

what it actually outputs is an arraylist of linked lists and each linked list contains a one digit move, but you'll notice it isnt ALL one digit moves.  Also any negative numbers you see in my lists are my number coded way of interpreting whether I've hit a forbidden number in my path or if I've hit my target

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use a graph search algorithm such as Dijkstra's algorithm. Have a look at that and other graph searches. I don't know enough to show you an implementation but it is a good place to start.